# How to custom draw a ListView using the OnDrawItem event when the ViewStyle is vsIcon

Tags: delphi

How can I custom draw a ListView to make it look like this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check this out [ask]. After you have carefully read it, check [Embarcadero's help resource](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TCustomListView_OnDrawItem.html). As a practice example I can offer you both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519742/drawing-a-checkbox-in-a-tlistview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116742/center-subitem-images-in-a-tlistview/52119415) answers. These examples will give you a way how to do it.

Comment: in google or embarcadero forum this dont code works when the property is ViewStyle := vsicon .......
All Topics in Google or Embarcadero ViewStyle: = vsreport or others ........
I want to do it with ViewStyle: = vsicon so I created this help topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw content of `TListView` in custom way very eae only if you will read help resources carefully.
Image below is a result of code running. The code attached after this picture.
[image]
*Component `ImageList1` that is attached to `TListView` has both width and height set to 24 pixels*

This one picture is the same `TListView` but without attached ImageList.
[image]

*Orange rectangle is a selected item*

Now go to the code.

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1AdvancedCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  Image: TBitmap;
  R: TRect;
  CenterH: Integer;
  CenterV: Integer;
  ImageIndex: Integer;
begin
  R := Item.DisplayRect(drBounds);
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Image := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      Bmp.SetSize(R.Width, R.Height);

      // Make fill for item
      if Item.Selected then
        Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWebOrange
      else
        Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clMoneyGreen;
      Bmp.Canvas.FillRect(Bmp.Canvas.ClipRect);

      // Output image associated with current item
      if Assigned(TListView(Sender).LargeImages) then
        begin
          TListView(Sender).LargeImages.GetBitmap(Item.ImageIndex, Image);
          CenterH := (R.Width - Image.Width) div 2;
          CenterV := (R.Height - Image.Height) div 2;
          Bmp.Canvas.Draw(CenterH, CenterV, Image);
        end;

      // Draw ready item's image onto sender's canvas
      Sender.Canvas.Draw(R.Left, R.Top, Bmp);
    finally
      Image.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You must be informed that size of each item of `TListView` in `vsIcon` ViewMode depend on the size of `TImageList` attached to control via `LargeImages` property. Than large image - than large item in `TListView`.